# What should be the type of state in pinia store using nuxt

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth, pinia

I am using pinia with nuxt and typescript to create stores.

This is code of auth store (with nuxt auth module) -

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('authStore', {
  getters: {
     isAuthenticated(state) {
       return state.$nuxt.$auth.loggedIn
     }
  }
})
```

Now the issue is, IDE gives typescript error -

> Property '$nuxt' does not exist on type '{} and {}'. ts(2339)

Comment: Did you check https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#typescript ?

Comment: yes I checked, I have added the required configs. but still the issue remains same.

Comment: `$nuxt` is not defined as part of the store state (nor should it be). Why do you think you can access `$nuxt` from the store like that?

Answer (score 0):

`state.$nuxt` tries to access a *state* property named `$nuxt` which does not exist (unless you create it yourself). The pinia docs say that `$nuxt` is injected into the *store*, so you should be able to access it via `this.$nuxt`.